# How to fit the Cauchy distribution to the data

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have data on financial returns, and I want to fit the Cauchy distribution and student distribution to that data. Furthermore I want to check the goodness of fit in both cases.
Where should I start from?

Comment: @Start with a choice of a programming language, or pre-built software.

Comment: thanks I'm using R. but I'm not sure how to do it. I mean do I have to estimate parameters of cauchy distribution?

Comment: Of course you have to estimate parameters--that's how you fit the distribution. You might start [here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=cauchy+distribution+parameter+estimation#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had a series of iid data $X_1, \dots, X_n$ that I assumed come from a Cauchy distribution with density
$$
f(x;\mu,\sigma)= \frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{1}{\pi(1+((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2}
$$
Here is how I would do that in R:
first, the log-density in R is the function

```
dcauchy(x,mu,sigma,log=TRUE)
```

then a function construction the log-likelihood function:

```
make_loglik <- function(x) {
          function(para) {
               sum(dcauchy(x,para[1],para[2],log=TRUE)) }
}
```

then actually making the loglik function:

loglik <- make_loglik(x)

and finally, maximizing this using `optim()` or some other optimization routine.

For the t-dist, you could just replace the cauchy density above with the t-density, but you should be aware that the t-likelihood is **unbounded** as a function of the degrees-of-freedom parameter! so just optimizing the likelihood might go very bad!

Comment: I have a question are yoou taking mu and sigma as mean and S.D. here or they are location and scale parameters?

Comment: mu and sigma are location/scale parameters! mean do not exist!

Comment: thanks, can we do this in that way                                         > log <- function(theta, x) {sum(-dcauchy(x, location = theta[1], scale = theta[2], log = TRUE))}     after that we can use nlm()             theta.start <- c(median(x), IQR(x)/2)
> out <- nlm(mlogl3, theta.start, x = x)
> theta.hat <- out$estimate

Comment: I already tried doing this but it saying "vote up requires 15 reputations "

Comment: could you please tell me how to check the distribution fit in R.